# Enable CORS with Google IAP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cors, google-iap

I'm are trying make an ajax call to my web api server from a third party JavaScript integration. However after enabling IAP on my API server, I'm unable to make the calls to my web apis from my integration server.
I have added my integration server as Authorized JavaScript origins in the Client ID for Web application.

Below is the error.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://webapiserver.com/apiendpoint1' from origin 'https://myintegration.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Please let me know if there is other configuration missing at my end.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide your API call example for troubleshooting?

Answer (score 5):

CORS requires unauthenticated OPTIONS request. Your API server needs to allow it, to do it, you need:

1. Add code to your app that responds to the OPTIONS requests.
2. Change the setting access_settings.cors_settings.allow_http_options to true so that IAP passes OPTIONS requests through to your application.

[More information about customizing IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/customizing#allowing_http_options_cors_preflight) in the official Google documentation.

This feature was not previously available, and proposed workaround existed:

In the same GCP project create App Engine services:

- A UI server
- An API server

The UI server makes calls to the API server. To get around the CORS problem, use Routing with a dispatch file: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#routing_with_a_dispatch_file

Normally, when the UI server wants to call API server, it calls `api-dot-MY_PROJECT.appspot.com`

In this workaround, the UI server calls itself with a specified path `("/api")`: `MY_PROJECT.appspot.com/api`

Since the UI server is calling itself, CORS does not apply.

Comment: This feature is currently not supported in Cloud IAP. But there is an open ticket for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78326322

Comment: Cloud IAP now supports CORS preflight requests.

Comment: Thanks Ani for info, I did update the answer to reflect current status of the implementation.