# Access IAP secured resource from JS using XHR requests?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, jwt, google-iap

I am trying to access Google APP engine which is secured using Google Cloud IAP(Identity Aware Proxy). I am able to access the resource using postman as well as any backend service like (Node or Python) by using the identity token. But as soon as I try to access it from browser using the same identity token, I get a 401 unauthorized error.

I am getting the identity token by following this article:
https://engineering.q42.nl/google-identity-aware-proxy/

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.withCredentials = true;

            xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
                if (this.readyState === 4) {
                    console.log(this.responseText);
                }
            });

            xhr.open("GET", "<appengine_url>", true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html,*/*");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <identity_token>");

            xhr.send(data);
```

Error message:
OPTIONS `my_url` 401

Access to XMLHttpRequest at `my_url` from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53163761/enable-cors-with-google-iap  I see the same problem, too. But the suggested solution doesn't work with Cloud IAP I guess. I can't find any setting to let IAP add these headers or to pass CORS preflighted requests (`OPTIONS`). Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I have not find a solution yet.

Comment: Good news: Cloud IAP supports CORS preflight requests. They added it a week ago or so.